# IDL command array_indices.pro

Tags: undefined, idl-programming-language

I 'm new to IDL and using IDL in command-line. When I want to invoke the function array_indices(), the error comes as:

```
>% Attempt to call undefined procedure/function: 'ARRAY_INDICES'.
>% Execution halted at: $MAIN$
```

But I have checked, under my lib subdirectory, array_indices.pro exits, whose path goes as: Applications/exelis/idl83/lib. Then why does it behave like this?
A similar problem occurs in another invoking command. I downloaded the textoidl.pro file and add it as

idl> !PATH = Expand_Path('+mydirectory\coyote')  + ';' + !PATH

the textoidl.pro is under the directory coyote, but I tried that, it says:

```
>textoidl.pro
>% Syntax error.
```

I also tried other command added by coyote lib, some, or I should say, most of them work well, but a few really responds as

```
>*.pro
>%Syntax error.
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Please show exactly what you typed to get the above errors.

Comment: IDL's path specification is not entirely transparent, unfortunately.  That said, I am fairly certain you are not setting the paths correctly.  What do you get when you type the following:  `IDL> HELP, !VERSION, /STRUC`?

Comment: I ask because I am not sure if this is an OS issue (i.e., is the semi-colon the path separator in Windows?).

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the following?

```
IDL> x = findgen(2, 3)
IDL> print, array_indices(x, [0, 3, 5])
% Compiled module: ARRAY_INDICES.
           0           0
           1           1
           1           2
```

One potential problem might be IDL's confusion between functions and array when indexing/calling with parentheses. Try:

```
IDL> compile_opt strictarr
```

first and then the above.